# How to get list of drivers installed in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: driver, windows-phone-8.1, wdk

How can i get list of all device drivers (KMDF/UMDF) installed in windows-phone 8.1. I need to get list of all device drivers and their details and print it in a windows-phone app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regular store application and not an Enterprise or RPAL application, correct? If so, then you can't.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. Is there anyway possible to find out which drivers are currently running on the device? Something like 'Device Manager' in Windows.

Comment: Not with a retail device. If you're an OEM you could use TShell to read the drivers registry keys. But if you were an OEM, you wouldn't be asking here. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I am trying to create an app like a system diagnostic tool.